# Is it possible to pull an array of strings from an Array whithin the document in Spring Boots MongoTemplate?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, criteria, mongotemplate

I have an array of strings:

```
List<String> namesArray = new ArrayList<>()
```

Then I have the following two documents in my MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "9873hihy9032u49083b98"
    },
    "type": "A",
    "config": {
        "names": ["Marc", "Franc"],
    }
}
```

---

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "803bkjiug34909832u40"
    },
    "type": "A",
    "config": {
        "names": ["Max", "Brian", "Marc"],
    }
}
```

I want to remove all the names that occurs in `namesArray` from the `config.names` array in each of the documents.

For example if the name **Marc** features in the array, it should be removed from both documents, etc.

I've tried this without any luck:

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("type").is("A").and("config.names").in(namesArray));
Update update = new Update().pull("config.names", query)
mongo.updateMulti(new Query(), update, Person.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$elemMatch`

See:

[mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

[spring data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-query)

Comment: I've actually looked at `$elemMatch` but I couldn't include it in the Query. No matter where I put it it gave me an error.